# Use Case for using Redis Server

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I want to ask why should we use Redis Server. As I am a Java/Spring programmer. I can create "static" List, Hash, Set etc. and they will remain in memory -- as Redis is also in memory database.

My Questions are below:
1. Do Radis also save data in disk?
2. Is Radis database is distributed? If yes then where I can see Radis Arcitect.
3. What is the advantage of using Redis. Instead of creating "static" List, Hash programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis stands for Remote Dictionary Service. Java structures are local, in-process. If you need multiple processes (most likely distributed among more than 1 server) sharing data, then you need some kind of shared memory exposed as a service, for example: either Sql, Memcache, or Redis... Redis is a good fit for temporary data, like session state, or cache, while Sql is the standard for relational data.
Redis can be configured to also store in disk storage  making it a permanent and resilent store.
Redis is not distributed unless you setup a Redis Clustet (multiple redis instances), but using redis is very common practice in distributed applications where many components need to share info.